# Share http Manager between requests

Tags: haskell

I'm using the library http-client and http-client-tls to make http requests.

The documentation https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client mentioned "It is highly advisable to share your Manager value throughout your application"

If I'm building a function that takes a `String` as an API HOST (i.e "http://localhost:3030", or "https://www.example.org") and makes a request to it, do I need to create two managers - a http Manager to share between http requests if the API host is `http`, and a https Manager to share between https requests if the API host is `https`?

What's the best practice to "share" the Manager between requests?

Is it possible to have a globally shared Manager or Managers (ssl and non-ssl)? Since a http request will be sent in an IO anyway, is it possible to  create globally shared Managers in an IO and then read the corresponding Manager within an IO whenever sending a http/https request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days, I just use [getGlobalManager](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.7/http-client-tls-0.3.5.3/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#v:getGlobalManager). Recently, Yesod were also made to use this by default. Also you don't need to use separate manager for http and https. A sample example demonstrating it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import           Network.HTTP.Client        (defaultManagerSettings, Manager)
import           Network.HTTP.Simple
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS (getGlobalManager)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    manager <- getGlobalManager

    printResponse manager "http://httpbin.org/get"
    printResponse manager "https://google.com"

printResponse :: Manager -> Request -> IO ()    
printResponse mgr url = do
  let request = setRequestManager mgr url
  response <- httpLBS request

  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++  show (getResponseStatusCode response)
  print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
  L8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody response
```

Comment: `getGlobalManager` sounds like it will create a global manager if doesn't exist and reuse the same one whenever the function is called. If so, does it make sense to let `printResponse` call `getGlobalManager` by itself.

Comment: @zhangchiqing I just looked at the code and it seems using it inside `printResponse` will likely create it two times, so I would avoid that approach.

Comment: The implementation of `getGlobalManager` seems like a singleton pattern that uses `IORef`. I tested in the REPL, if I call `newTlsManager` twice, the second time is as slow as the first time. But If I call `getGlobalManager` twice, the second time is way faster than the first time. Isn't the second time using the cached Manager created from the first time?

Comment: @zhangchiqing I have to see the code once more to confirm it. I will try to see it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @Sibi. My only concern is if there are multiple calls to `getGlobalManager` simultaneously before the first `Manager` gets cached, then there will be multiple `Manager` created. But I think such chance can be mitigated by calling `getGlobalManager` at application startup phase as a "warm up". No?

Comment: @LeoZhang I just confirmed this with Michael Snoyman: Using `getGlobalManager` inside `printResponse` shouldn't be problematic as it's cached and multiple `Manger` won't be created.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Sibi

Comment: @Sibi `getGlobalManager` internally uses `globalManager` which uses `unsafePerformIO`. Is this really safe? Any issues you've faced in production?